# PdfMake custom table cell subdivision

Tags: pdfmake

I'm using pdfMake to generate a document dynamically, but my client wants a specific layout inside the table's cells based on value's type.

In these two images you can see my current solution, there are two "date" types and one "degree".

[image: Example 1][image: Example 2]

I've set up this layout using a table inside a table, adding some fixed margin to try to compensate for borders, but it isn't working very well. Lines are overlapping or does not fill the cell at all.

Is there a way to get cell's size and compensate dynamically the margin, or maybe a simpler way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only working solution I found is to duplicate the number of columns and use `colSpan` accordingly if I have a particular element type or not.

This is the result:

[image]